# Trix editor validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, trix

Using Trix editor via Rails view helpers.

`= form.rich_text_area :description, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Description'`

Have some model 'required' validation for description.

The normal Rails behavior of wrapping fields with `field_with_errors` is not happening.

Has anyone managed to get Trix and the normal Rails validation behavior to work together?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this way..

```
- if job.errors[:description].count > 0
    .form-with-errors
       = form.rich_text_area :description, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Description'
            .invalid-feedback.d-block
              - job.errors[:description].each do |error|
                = error
```

and..

```
.form-with-errors {
  trix-editor {
    border-color: #dc3545;
  }
}
```